# somthing wrong with Hosting a website in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, web, webdriver

I uploaded the project folder to my google drive and tried to check if its working, but the different HTML pages are not connected. when I run it in visual studio it is working.
[enter image description here][1]

this is the links I got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzstg.png
and this is the project link: https://1d32azc8zkmyflajfbr0bw-on.drv.tw/www.EnglishMaster.com/
can someone help me and tell me why the HTML files are not connected?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the relative path of you  tag, you wrote that:

```
<a class="btn" href="/howwork.html">How Does It Work</a>
```

You need to replace /howwork.html with `href="/www.EnglishMaster.com/howwork.html"`

Read about abosulte path and relative path, and how a webserver serve static file.

Comment: its still not working... do u have any idea why? https://1d32azc8zkmyflajfbr0bw-on.drv.tw/www.EnglishMaster.com/

Comment: change this `<a class="btn" href="/howwork.html">How Does It Work</a>` to
`<a class="btn" href="/www.EnglishMaster.com/howwork.html">How Does It Work</a>`

Comment: yes I changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: if i see your souce code online now, is not changed.

Comment: oh yea thank u i saved only in visualstudio now it works

Comment: Ok! read about absoulute path and relative path. If i answer you give me an up

Comment: i think i gave you. i have another problem when im going to index and than to highscore and than index again its says error do u know why? i changed it also in high score, u can see if you go highscore and then index it is working so what is the problem?